# Perl: return execution to the caller but then wake up again

Tags: perl

Suppose, we have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl /home/user/myscript.pl
echo "hello"
```

myscript.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "First\n";
#here I want the script to sleep for 5 seconds
#and return the execution back to the caller
#so, "hello" will be printed
#but after 5 seconds the script will wake up from sleep and run the next line

print "Second\n";
```

How can I this?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
perl /home/user/myscript.pl &
sleep 5
echo "hello"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
```

-or-

```
#!/bin/bash
perl /home/user/myscript.pl
echo "hello"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sleep(5);
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
exit(0) if fork();
...
```